# Bug of $geoWithin $box mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the document in my MongoDB like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd11de2c562bc659e4ba90b"),
    "_location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -124.364971, 
            45.427363
        ]
    },
}
```

"_location" index "2dsphere"

when I query $geoWithin $box but result wrong:

```
db.collection.find({
    "location": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$box": [
   [41.48400081976297,6.3656217405539515],
   [-71.54334293023703,81.44766980531374]
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Like this image, I want to search red box but mongodb query blue box, How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Did you read the documentation? See ["Big" Polygons](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#-big--polygons) Also see https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-30-features-big-polygon

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank your infomation, I checked it and change to big polygons, my query have result better